# Assigning default value to T:Float type parameter

Tags: haxe

I have a class that I wanted dynamic on what type to accept, but still be of type float. I have added an example class below. Simply put, I want a class that can contain either Ints or Floats (or abstracts(Float)), but the type parameter doesn't like being assigned something that should actually fit it.

```
class Container<T:Float>
{
    public function new(aValue:T = 0.0) 
    {
    }

    public function example():T 
    {
        return 16.0;
    }
```

In this example, I get two compiler errors. The fist one is the default value of the constructor `new(aValue:T = 0.0`. A simple fix is to set the value as dynamic, but I like my code neater than this. The second error is in the return value of example(). It won't let me return 16.0, as it is not a T instance.

My question: Is this doable and, if not, should I either use different class definitions for every type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you don't really need the generic type "T".

Here's what I came up with given your constraints.  The class "Container" is not generic, and merely contains a Float constructor.  This still allows it, however, to accept any value that can be implicitly cast to Float, which includes any `abstract` as long as they define casting rules.

```
package ;

class Main
{
    public static function main()
    {
        new Container(); // default
        new Container(1); // Int
        new Container(2.3); // Float
        new Container(new UnifiesWithFloat(4.5)); // Float abstract
    }
}

class Container
{
    public function new(aValue:Float = 0.8) 
    {
        trace('aValue is $aValue');
    }
}

abstract UnifiesWithFloat(Float) from Float to Float
{
    inline public function new(value:Float)
    {
        this = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this simple solution works quite well for some situations, it wouldn't work for abstracts that do not contain `from Float to Float`. 

If you could assign values to a type parameter that is a Float, you could then support any kind of abstract that support float operation overloads.

Of course, if there are no way to assign values to a float type parameter, then a simple float container is the best and most efficient solution.

Comment: Wait, a shower helped. My previous comment doesn't work as an abstract that is not strictly a float would not work as a type. What I'd really need is some way to specify the possible operator overloads in a type, and I don't think that's possible. I shall then select your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could come up for this issue with a `cast` and with own resolving of the optional parameters.

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        $type(new Container(1));
        $type(new Container(1).example());
        new Container(1).example();

        $type(new Container(1.0));
        $type(new Container(1.0).example());
        new Container(1.0).example();
    }
}

class Container<T:Float> {
    public var value:T;

    public function new(aValue:T) {
        this.value = cast (aValue != null ? aValue : 0);
    }

    public function example():T {
        return cast 16;
    }
}
```

This logs:
`Test.hx:3: characters 14-30 : Warning : Container<Int>
Test.hx:4: characters 14-40 : Warning : Int
Test.hx:7: characters 14-32 : Warning : Container<Float>
Test.hx:8: characters 14-42 : Warning : Float`